# Resizing background images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-resizing

This is really for informational and learning purposes while learning more about JavaScript and CSS. I have a local browser index page that I wanted to rotate the background image onload. After looking around and playing with different solutions, I settled on this for the basic rotate functionality:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function rotate()
{
   var imgArray = new Array("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg");
   var aImg = Math.floor(Math.random()*imgArray.length);
   var img = imgArray[aImg];
   document.body.style.background = "url(" + img + ") no-repeat";
   document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="rotate()">
</body>
</html>
```

During the process, before I just set the `backgroundSize`as cover to fill the window, I was playing with the idea of resizing the images before setting them as the background image after they are selected from the array.

I have done a lot of searching, and the only real working solutions I have found rely on selecting the element by ID, but that also requires that the image has an ID associated, such as in the IMG property in the HTML code.  Here the image is selected and set in the JavaScript with CSS.

I have tried setting the image dimensions with `img.width` / `img.height` and `img.style.width` / `img.style.height`, as well as a few other random solutions I have come across, but whenever I try to change these the image either does not change or it does not show at all.

```
function rotate()
{
   var imgArray = new Array("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg");
   var aImg = Math.floor(Math.random()*imgArray.length);
   var img = imgArray[aImg];
   image = rsize(img);
   document.body.style.background = "url(" + image + ") no-repeat";
   document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
}
function rsize(image)
{
   image.style.width = "300px";
   image.style.height = "300px";
   return image;
}
```

I know I am probably doing something wrong here. Is there a way, in this circumstance, that I can resize these images?  Or is there a better way to construct this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must set `image.style.width` and `image.style.height` on an actual image DOM object, not on the URL as you are currently trying to do.

As an image object is not used for background images, you can't really directly do what you're trying to do for a background image.

You could use the CSS `background-size` property, but that is fairly new and is not supported in versions of IE prior to IE9.  If you were using that, you would set the actual size for that, not `"cover"`.

You could also use an actual DOM image and then present that DOM image as centered in your page if that's what you're really trying to do.

For example, here's how you create a DOM image object, assign it a URL, set it's size and insert it into your page:

```
var imgArray = new Array("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg");
var aImg = Math.floor(Math.random()*imgArray.length);
var imgURL = imgArray[aImg];
var img = new Image();
img.src = imgURL; 
img.style.width = "300px";
img.style.height = "300px";
img.id = "centeredImage";
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

You could then use CSS to position is in the center of your page if you wanted.

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/jqMtV/

Comment: That is similar to one of the solutions I was trying earlier, but without the `appendChild`. But it still does not work with the image elements. This is still good info for me, thanks.

Comment: @jb11 - I fixed a typo in my code sample.  I've also implemented a working demo where you can see the CSS that centers the image too: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/jqMtV/

Comment: @jfriend00 That did fix it, and it is a bit more along the lines of what I was envisioning as the solution. Plus I think it opens up the ability for me to play with the CSS a lot more.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, you have no `<img>` elements you could (re)size (btw, they would not need ids to be selectable). Your use of `rsize(imgArray[aImg])` operates on the array members, which are *strings* and not DOM elements, so setting values on their non-existent `style` property would throw an error.

Yet, you're already on the right way with using the [`backgroundSize` style property](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/). Just don't set it to `cover`, but to the size you need!

```
document.body.style.backgroundSize = "300px 300px";
```

If you would want to use a `<img>` element, add this at the end of your `<body>`:

```
<img src="some.jpg" style="position:fixed; z-index:-1; width:100%; height:100%" />
```

Comment: A drawback of `backgroundSize` is that is not supported in IE prior to IE9.

Comment: I primarily use Firefox, for which I use this custom index page.  Like I said, the cover property pretty much took care of my issue anyway, but I was still interested in coming up with alternate methods to solve the issue. But that is definitely good information.  Thanks.

Comment: While I still intend to play around with different approaches, this is a simpler solution to my resizing issue.

Comment: @jfriend00 I only really use IE for certain things, like checking cross-platform compatibility when creating pages that will be published. I am not saying I will never need to do this in the future, but my immediate project was focused on a local index page for Firefox, which is my primary browser.

Comment: @jb11 - OK, if you are the only viewer of that web page.  Next time, that would make your question clearer if you only need to target one particular browser.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that I made that clear by "local browser index page" in my original post.